# Can not update Intellij because of error permission denied?

Tags: 13.04, intellij

My Intellij version is 12.1 and new version is 12.1.4 so I want to update it but after dowloading new file it can not proceed because of file permission denied. Can any one tell me how to change permission so I can update my Intellij?

Comment: are you trying the update as root?

Comment: No I didn't. I just click "update and restart" button as the Intellij start and can not proceed.

Comment: please see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23308. Try changing the owner of Idea installation directory from root to user(you)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to the `/bin` Folder of the "Idea", for Example (or in my case):

```
/opt/idea-IC-135.690/bin
```

and there start the App, with sudo.
Like this:

```
sudo ./idea.sh
```

Just update,

if you have any `/tmp` memory space problem, restart your OS and try the step again.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Just noting that it took me a few restarts as sudo to get the update button to show. In the end, it worked!

Comment: Great, I think you can change the folder(/idea-IC-135.690/bin) permission also, to don't have to open idea with sudo.

Comment: I didn't think of that, I just gave idea.sh 777 permissions since this is my dev machine.

Comment: On my machine (OS X), it was `cd /Applications/Intellij IDEA 14/Contents/Mac OS` then sudo `./idea`.

Comment: I get: "Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment" Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I found a fix, if you get: "Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment". Try running with "sudo -E" instead.

Answer (score 46):

Had the same issue with Idea IntelliJ 2016.2

You should set the user and group of your idea folder to yourself. (or a group that you share with other users, if you need)

In my case, it was because some files in idea were assigned to root:root, and I didn't see the point.

So I ran: 
`sudo chown -R jcharlet:jcharlet /opt/idea-IC-162.1121.32`

Comment: I think this is a better solution than the previous one ;)

Comment: This solution will solve the issue every time without the need to restart with root. Much better solution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was unable to update IntelliJ Idea. Assigning permissions to my user solved it for me.

Answer (score 31):

The solution Jeremy provided is the best one on my opinion. What I would recommend is to use whoami utility call to set parameters of the current console user automatically like

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/idea-ICblablabla`

Comment: The cleanest solution from my point of view.

Comment: The best solution, works out of the box and fixes the problem for good.

Comment: I ran into a similar error and this worked for me "sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Caskroom/intellij-idea-ce/"

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Manjaro Linux and installed through `pacmac`.

All I had to do was type `sudo idea` and start idea as root to update.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using JetBrains Toolbox, you can update your IntelliJ directly from there. Open the toolbox and click update next to the app you want to update (it will either show up as a button or by clicking on the 3 dots next to the app).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with PhpStorm-183.4886.46. None of the answers dealing with permissions worked. In the end the problem was that there were several fsnotifier64 processes still running when PhpStorm quit to update that i had to kill manually

Answer (score 0):

Running the IDEA would not be a good idea to run the Binary file of IntelliJ with sudo permission. Just modify the apprpriate xx.rule file under /etc/udev/rules.d, which has the specification of the USB port want to be accessed and then run intelliJ normally. Just Modify the MODE Attribute as it could be read and written for other users as well, something like 0666.

Answer (score 0):

i am using ubuntu and this is what i did !

go to the location /opt and open a terminal.

[opt folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwYpL.png)

type `sudo chmod 777 idea-IU-211.7142.45` and hit enter.

note : this is my folder name and it can be different for you. just give intellij folder name there.
go to intellij idea Help section and click check for update.

now you should have the permission

Answer (score 0):

Most likely itellij was installed using root privilege and as such is owned by user:group root:root. Just change user:group and you can run the updates. No need to give 777 permission.

sudo chown -R userX:userX /opt/idea